# Get multiple records from two tables having primary and foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql

![enter image description here][1]In the First Table `tblserialnumbersprimary` i have a primary  field called as `serialNoId` ,this field is repeating multiple times in the second table `tblserialnumbers`. when we are inserting multiple records with that `serialNoId`.
I want to get Distinct records from the first table i.e `tblserialnumbersprimary`  and corresponding multiple records from the dependent table i.e `tblserialnumbers` in MySQL

## First Table Fields are:

```
tblserialnumbersprimary (serialNoId,serialPO,serialProductNo,
SerialNumberMode,serialNoAutoPrefix,serialDateOfCreation,
serialModifiedBy,serialStatus)
```

## Second Table Fields are:

```
tblserialnumbers(serialId,serialNoId,
serialNo,serialNoBatchId![enter image description here][1])
```

I tried With This Joins Query.But its giving multiple records of first table

```
select * FROM   tblserialnumbersprimary
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblserialnumbers
ON (tblserialnumbersprimary. serialNoId = tblserialnumbers.serialNoId )
```

## First Table values are:

```
 serialNoId serialPO    serialProductNo SerialNumberMode    serialNoAutoPrefix  serialDateOfCreation    serialModifiedBy    serialStatus
1   PO1 PROD121 Automatic   TCS-03  2/25/2014 12:00:00 AM   admin   0
2   PO2 PROD345 Automatic   TCS-03  2/25/2014 12:00:00 AM   admin   1 
3   PO5 PROD816 Automatic       2/26/2014 12:00:00 AM   admin   1
4   PO1 PROD121 Automatic   GTS-03  2/26/2014 12:00:00 AM   admin   1
```

## Second Table values are:

```
serialId serialNoId serialNo    serialNoBatchId
1   1        TCS-03-PROD121-1   batch1
2   1        TCS-03-PROD121-2   
3   1        TCS-03-PROD121-3   batch3
4   1        TCS-03-PROD121-4   
5   1        100    
6   1        101    
1   2        TCS-03-PROD345-1   batch1
2   2        TCS-03-PROD345-2   
3   2        TCS-03-PROD345-3   batch3
4   2        TCS-03-PROD345-4   
1   3        --1    
2   3        --2    
3   3        --3    
4   3        --4    
5   3         12    
6   3         13    
7   3         11    
1   4      -PROD816-1       batch1
2   4      -PROD816-2           batch2
1   5       GTS-03-PROD121-1    batch1
2   5       GTS-03-PROD121-2    
3   5       GTS-03-PROD121-3    batch3
4   5       GTS-03-PROD121-4
```

Comment: Use [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Can you post your sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Use alias and join for record in multiple table.

```
 For i.e. `SELECT table2.id, 
              table1.pid, 
              table1.color, 
              table2.pname, 
              table2.image 
           FROM   tbl_productcolor table1 
               JOIN tbl_product table2 ON table1.pid = table2.id;`
```

Apply your table in this way you can get all the data.